# prove that $\int_{a}^{b}(|f-{\frac{1}{b-a}} \int_{a}^{b}f|)~dx \le {(b-a)}\int_b^{a}|f'| ~dx$

Tags: real-analysis

where $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Apparently it has something to with the fundamental theorem of calculus although I'm not entirely sure how you would apply it to this example. How would I proceed? Any ideas?

Comment: Please fix the title. The question is not clear at all.

Comment: I've done my best to turn it into something not too different from what the OP wrote that still looks as if it might be true. :)

Comment: Hint: Adding a constant to $f$ doesn't change either side. So replacing $f$ with $f - M$, where $M$ is the average of $f$ on the interval, turns this into a slightly easier problem, namely: Prove that $$\int_a^ b |g(x)| dx \le (b-a) \int_a^b |g'(x)| dx$$ whenever $\int_a^b g(x) dx = 0$. [Note that in your original problem statement, the $a$ and $b$ on the second integral should almost certainly be reversed, as I've done in my restatement, for it's false right now for $f(x) = x$, $a = -1, b = 1$.]

Comment: Write, $\displaystyle g(x) = f(x) - \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)\,dt \implies \displaystyle \int_a^b g(t)\,dt = 0$, 

Since, $g$ is continuous, $\exists\, c \in (a,b),$s.t. $g(c) = 0.$

Now, from the mean value theorem, $\exists\, d \in (a,b)$, such that

$$\displaystyle \begin{align} \int_a^b |g(t)|\,dt &= \int_a^b \left|\int_c^t g'(u)\,du\right|\,dt \\ &\le \int_a^b \int_c^t |g'(u)|\,du\,dt \\&= (b-a)\int_c^d |g'(u)|\,du\end{align}$$

Since, $\displaystyle \int_c^d |g'(u)|\,du \le \int_a^b |g'(u)|\,du$, the inequality follows.

Answer (score 3):

By the mean value theorem for integrals, there is a point $c\in (a,b)$ such that $$f(c) = \frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b f\, dx.$$ Thus

\begin{align*}
\int_a^b |f(x) - \frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b f|\, dx &= \int_a^b |f(x) - f(c)|\, dx\\
& = \int_a^c |f(x) - f(c)|\, dx + \int_c^b |f(x) - f(c)|\, dx\\
&= \int_a^c |\int_x^c f'(t)\, dt|\, dx + \int_c^b |\int_c^x f'(t)\, dt|\, dx\\
&\le \int_a^c \int_x^c |f'(t)|\, dt\, dx + \int_c^b \int_c^x |f'(t)|\, dt\, dx\\
&=\int_a^c \int_a^t |f'(t)|\, dx\, dt + \int_c^b \int_t^b |f'(t)|\, dx\, dt\\
&= \int_a^c (t - a)|f'(t)|\, dt + \int_c^b (b - t)|f'(t)|\, dt\\
&\le (c - a) \int_a^c |f'(t)|\, dt + (b - c) \int_c^b |f'(t)|\, dt\\
&\le (c - a) \int_a^b |f'(t)|\, dt + (b - c) \int_a^b |f'(t)|\, dt\\
&= (b - a) \int_a^b |f'(t)|\, dt.
\end{align*}